# how to add spring security oauth2 with web security

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

1. I can build REST services with spring-security-oauth2
2. I can build website security with spring-security
   And as you know, oauth2 has oauth-server, resource and client side. But I cannot put them together. I want to know how to build oauth2 website that I can login(session) with browser and I can use it as secure REST services(with access token). Any help? Thanks very much.

Comment: Did you found your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert in Spring, but [Spring security examples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/tests/annotation) link has some examples how to implement OAuth2.0 servers and resource servers.